# Write-protected USB stick

Tags: usb-drive, read-only

I have a USB Stick that seems to be write-protected. I already searched and tried a lot of solutions, but they don't work for me. E.g. I tried:

```
hdparm -r0 /dev/sdb
```

but that does not change anything.

```
badblocks –v
```

did not show any errors on the disk. Also gparted or the disk-utiliy tool could not make the usb stick work again. In gparted it says I have to create a partition table first, but when I do it it gives me an input/output error and tells me it is an unkown partition table.

I also tried it with Windows, but that was also not successful. Does anyone have other ideas how to make the USB stick writeable again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to identify manufacturer of this stick, look the vendor id `dmesg |tail -5` or `lsusb`, then download appropriate firmware soft (*for example windows AlcorMP*) then reformat your stick with last one. In fact that do not only format but also flash the usb microchip.

> NB: I'm not sure that this question is ubuntu specific, it should
>   rather  be moved to superuser.com